# Is there any site that shows me what are older packages which are replaced by newer ones?

Tags: packages, incompatibility

Currentyl I am using a template from our university which is from 2010. I added some packages etc. but now I am not sure if there are "duplicates" of packages I am using.

For example I have

```
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Where I would say {color} is not needed any longer? There are some more packages where I cannot say if there are newer ones which replaces them. So is there some ressource where stand something like:

color -> xcolor (xcolor provide the same as colour and add features)

Or may even a discrete package which test my code if there are "old" packages or if I have some compability issues?

Comment: If you are looking for a specific package, you can take a look at its CTAN page, and it will possibly tell you that it's deprecated. You can also take a look at the [`l2tabu`](https://ctan.org/pkg/l2tabu?lang=en) (which, ironically, had its last update quite some time ago :P), or you can load the [`nag`](https://ctan.org/pkg/nag?lang=en) package, which will tell you the most obvious problems.

Comment: For compatibility issues and loading order, check http://www.macfreek.nl/memory/LaTeX_package_conflicts and https://ctan.org/pkg/pkgloader

Comment: ctan.org does show obsolesence, if the package author deems it:  https://ctan.org/pkg/getargs (not the "OBSOLETE" seal on the left)

Comment: Not all new packages are improvements.  Some have very annoying "features" which should never have been unleashed upon the world.